# Unable to add attachment to Office JS Add-in

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js, add-in

I have created an EWS request to attach an email but i receive empty value from it but has "succeeded" status.
Btw.

I first created an makeEwsRequestAsync request for saving email to draft and it already works but when i try to add attachment to it using this request it didnt add. Any suggestions or help please

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
function createAttachment() {

    var request =
        '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
        'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
        'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
        'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
        '  <soap:Body>' +
        '    <CreateAttachment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
        '      <ParentItemId Id="'+itemID+'" />' +
        '      <Attachments>' +
        '        <t:ItemAttachment>' +
        '          <t:Name>Please</t:Name>' +
        '           <t:Message>' +
        '               <t:ItemClass>IPM>Note</t:ItemClass>' +
        '               <t:Subject>test</t:Subject>' +
        '               <t:Body BodyType="Text">my test</t:Body>' +
        '           </t:Message>' +
        '        </t:ItemAttachment>' +
        '      </Attachments>' +
        '    </CreateAttachment>' +
        '  </soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';
    return request;
}

</script>
```

This is my create Attachment EWS request

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">


    function composeMail(emailSubject, emailDescription) {
        var subject= subjectPrefix + " " + emailSubject;
        var request =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
            '               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
            '               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
            '               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"' +
            '               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
            '  <soap:Header>' +
            '    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />' +
            '  </soap:Header>' +
            '  <soap:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
            '    <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">' +
            '      <m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
            '        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="drafts" />' +
            '      </m:SavedItemFolderId>' +
            '      <m:Items>' +
            '            <t:Message>' +
            '              <t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>' +
            '              <t:Subject>' + subject + '</t:Subject>' +
            '              <t:Body BodyType="HTML">' + emailDescription + '</t:Body>' +
            '              <t:Importance>Low</t:Importance>' +
            '              <t:ToRecipients>' +
            '                <t:Mailbox>' +
            '                  <t:EmailAddress>' + recepient + '</t:EmailAddress>' +
            '                </t:Mailbox>' +
            '              </t:ToRecipients>' +
            '              <t:IsRead>false</t:IsRead>' +
            '            </t:Message>' +
            '          </m:Items>' +
            '        </m:CreateItem>' +
            '  </soap:Body>' +
            '</soap:Envelope>';
        return request;
    }
</script>
```

This is my create Email EWS request

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
    function send() {
        var request =
            '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
            'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
            'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"' +
            'xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">' +
            '  <soap:Body>' +
            '    <SendItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
            '    SaveItemToFolder="true">' +
            '      <ItemIds>' +
            '        <t:ItemId Id="' + itemID + '"/>' +
            '      </ItemIds>' +
            '    </SendItem>' +
            '  </soap:Body>' +
            '</soap:Envelope>';
        return request;
    }

</script>
```

This is my send EWS Request and i'm calling them using

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
    function sendRequest(emailSubject, emailDescription, emailItemID) {
        // Create a local variable that contains the mailbox.
        try {
            itemID = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
            Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(
                composeMail(emailSubject, emailDescription), callbackCompose);
            Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(
                createAttachment(), callbackAttachment);
            Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(
                send(), callbackSend);
        } catch (error) {
            $("#id-error-msg").text(error);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you able to use the attachments API to create attachments instead of makeEwsRequest? [addFileAttachmentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.6/office.context.mailbox.item#addfileattachmentasyncuri-attachmentname-options-callback). Is there a particular reason you were using makeEwsRequest instead?

Comment: I need to send email even when in read mode of the email, but based on what i have read and tried, the addFileAttachmentAsync works only when the user is in compose mode. So i switch to EWS request. Please let me know if its possible with it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The methods supported in makeEwsRequestAsync is limited. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services . In particular, CreateAttachment is not supported via makeEwsRequestAsync. To send a new email, have you looked into using graph API? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response :). Btw. I was able to make it work, but requires me to modify a lot. First, I remove the 2 EWS request (Send & Create attachment) then i added the attachment using Mime in the create item request. I can get the MimeContent using a request for the Exchange Server.

Comment: Also, regarding graph API. I tried using the restUrl but somehow it returns undefined in Outlook for desktop but in Outlook web works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution. If you can, feel free to post your solution as an answer to help others who may have the same question.

Comment: And for restUrl, it can depend on your version of Outlook Desktop. The restUrl API was introduced in Requirement Set 1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to manipulate emails from a compose mode, you may refer to this documentation by Microsoft team. I believe its quite more simple and comprehensive.

-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-and-remove-attachments-to-an-item-in-a-compose-form

Otherwise if you want to manipulate emails from a read mode. There can be two options to do it.

One is by using Rest API. Though, there are some requirements you need to met to make this request. Mine doesn't work on Desktop but works on Web but you can refer to this link if you want to try it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api

Upon encountering the minimum requirement issue. I found a way to make it work using Exchange Web Service request (EWS). It mainly uses XML files to send request to exchange web service and return a response.

However, i found that i need to get the MimeContent of that email to be able to add to my CreateItem xml request. Please check this link for more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getitem-operation-email-message

Then, I added the existing item to a new email by using its MimeContent. You can check it out using this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-add-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bad XML to me eg

```
'<t:ItemClass>IPM>Note</t:ItemClass>' +
```

Would produce a validation error on the server (you should see that in the EWS responses from the server eg your request should be

```
'<t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>'
```

Comment: Is there other approach that i can use?

Comment: Have you tried to look at results of the EWS operation that is being returned? they would have told you the first error was happening so its sounds like you not using the results to diagnose the problem

Comment: Okay, now i see the error in the response and it gives me this message "The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application." with faultcode "ErrorAccessDenied". It's my first time to try this one. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please clarify which EWS request is returning the error and fault code? And which platform you are using to test this, Outlook Web, Outlook for Windows, etc?

Comment: Hi! I the error "ErrorAccessDenied" returned when i am adding <attachment> object in the xml. But when i remove it. It goes well and save in the drafts folder. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am testing it using Outlook  for windows btw.